# How to add consecutive elements of a list?

Tags: python, list

If I have the following list:

```
x = [0, 1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]
```

And I have a number m = 4. From each element I have to consecutively add the next element to it until I reach a sum that is greater than or equal to 4. Then, I have to output the list containing how many numbers I had to add, including the starting one.So the output for this example would be:

```
y = [4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 7, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

The first element 4 means that starting from x[0], it took 3 more elements for the sum to be 4, thus y[0] = 4.The end zeros signify that there is no possible way to get the sum 4.

Comment: What did you try before posting here?

Comment: Could you add an example of your own coding attempt to solve this? So we can see were you are stuck..

Comment: FYI, lists elements in Python are comma separated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add consecutive elements of a list, I recommend two steps:

1. Grab the slice of the list that you want.
2. Use the **sum** function to add all the elements.

You get a slice of a list with the start and end elements -- remembering that the end element is not included in the slice, so you need to add 1 to the position of the last item you want.

In general, if you want elements **start** through **last**, you grab that slice with

```
y_slice = y[start:(last+1) ]   # The parentheses aren't needed
```

To get the sum of that slice you simply feed it to the function:

```
slice_sum = sum(y_slice)
```

or

```
slice_sum = sum( y[start:(last+1) ] )
```

Now, you need to figure out how to run through useful values of **start** and **last**.  Have fun.

Comment: Good, this answer only guides the OP, without offering him the code on a golden plate!

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: This is going to be really slow. There's an O(len(x)) solution based on maintaining the sum and slice size incrementally and using the information for one element to compute the information for the next.

Comment: @user2357112: I am well aware of that.  However, OP is not yet facile with list slices and nested loops.  I'm trying to help him at his level of comfort.